# C# Visual Studio Setup with a .config located in a custom path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

I would like to make a Setup with Visual Studio of "My App". I need to put "My App" executable in "C:\Program Files(x86)\My App" folder and the "My App.config" in "C:\Users\Public\My Company\My App.config".

How can I tell to My App that it must use the custom .config path for reading settings?

Comment: Is any update? Please check if my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read your app.config as the xml file.

I assume the app is a console app and here is a code example you can refer to.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Public\MyCompany\MyApp.config";
            GetSettings(path);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static void GetSettings(string path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader
                (
                    new FileStream(
                        path,
                        FileMode.Open,
                        FileAccess.Read,
                        FileShare.Read)
                );
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                string xmlIn = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                doc.LoadXml(xmlIn);
                foreach (XmlNode child in doc.ChildNodes)
                    if (child.Name.Equals("Settings"))
                        foreach (XmlNode node in child.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (node.Name.Equals("add"))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["key"].Value);
                                Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["value"].Value);
                                
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("******************");
                        }
                            
                                
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(path +" is not correct");
            }
         
        }
```

You can get the result like the following:

[image]